# Bootstrap 3 in line form or input group

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a search form, something like below..

http://tinypic.com/r/2py0scy/8

I am new to front end development and confused if an in-line form or a input group should be used?

The issue with inline forms is I am unable to size the input box (width) so any pointer there would also be really helpful.

Thanks!

Code Update

from home.HTML

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form">

    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Discover">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Go</button>


</form>
```

from the layouts - application.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
<%= yield %>
</div>
```

Comment: please, share your code and someone could help you easier

Comment: The code for the inline form is something like this..
''
''<form class="form-inline" role="form">
'' 
'' <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Discover">
'' <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Go</button>
''
''
''</form>
''
the issue is this is not resizable, I am not able to extend this with CSS effectively

Comment: It's important to show the context, I mean, the html container for the form, and please, update your own question, the comments is not a good place to put code.

Comment: Yeah, sorry about that. Still getting used to this forum. I have updated my initial question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play with the width in Bootstrap, see the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) and the use the columns:

For instance, if you want a form on the right and the width at the 50% of the container, you can do:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        This is div on the left
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <input class="form-control input-lg" type="text" placeholder="Discover">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Go</button>
    </form>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

The previous code, is designed to change the behavior on small devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use both depending on what you're trying to accomplish. Bootstrap is well-documented, did you read their documentation regarding forms ? http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

By default input items are 100% width in bootstrap (e.g. they fill the containing element they are in). For instance:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text input">
```

would result in a 100% width input field and

```
<style>
.smallwidth {max-width: 200px;}
</style>

<div class='smallwidth'><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Text input"></div>
```

would result in a 200px width input field, because it is restricted by the outer div I put around it.

Comment: If I add a button to this, it comes to to new line. Is possible to add one in-line?

Comment: I just tried the following code snippet from getbootstrap.com/components and I'd say yes based on the result of that : <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>

Comment: Firstly Thanks! Yes this is something similar to what I have using the inline-form, http://tinypic.com/r/f043uf/8 . Again I am not able to do this as 100% or resize the text box to fit the panel better.

Comment: Copy and paste the following , please upvote or sign as solved if this answers your question =) <style type="text/css">
  /*Change the max-width to whatever value you like*/
  .myCss{max-width: 300px; }
 </style>
  <div class="myCss">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="button">Go!</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>